# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.'XXXX' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

i am trying to add data to reservation table.I have a Reservation obj Reservation object. and i am setting the text property value of winform textboxes.

```
objReservation.ID_Reservation =idReservationTxT.Text;
        objReservation.ID_Customer = idCustomerTxt.Text;
        objReservation.ID_Room = roomTxt.Text;
        ......
         Common.Intance.SaveChanges();
```

While Saving the data, I am getting error :

```
    An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'Room' when invoking System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid. See the inner exception for details
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Room_D41B83663C39A7974A2F04AE9E23516E208F56892D99841049D88CB5D77C0A7A' to type 'System.String
```

An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'Room' when invoking
surely my ID_Room is the problem

class Room

```
public class Room
    {
        public Room()
        {
            this.Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
        }
        [Key]
        [StringLength(20)]
        [Required]
        public string ID_Room { get; set; }
        public int ID_TypeRoom { get; set; }
        public int ID_StatusRoom { get; set; }

        public virtual TypeRoom TypeRoom { get; set; }
        public virtual StatusRoom StatusRoom { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }

    }
```

class Reservation

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public Reservation()
        {
            this.Bills = new HashSet<Bill>();
            this.Services = new HashSet<Service>();
           
        }
        [Key]
        [StringLength(20)]
        [Required]
        public string  ID_Reservation { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]

        public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ID_Room { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ID_Customer { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
          
        public virtual ICollection<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Comment: Change your member var names Room and Customer, they can't be same as that of a type.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Can you explain more?